Triggers on parent and child table and order of execution respectively
lets say I have table A and table B. Table B is the child table and has a foreign key to table A. I have other mirrored tables, lets say table C(mirror for table A) and table D(mirror for B). Both tables B and D have a foreign key to its respective table. I have created a trigger on table A in order when its inserted on table A, the trigger inserts the same on table C and the same for table B for table D. My doubt is that in the same transaction, I insert on tables A and B, and maybe the trigger for table B could execute first than the trigger for table A causing an error on table D because the parent foreign key is not found yet on table C. Can it happen and how can I fix it?.


That can't happen as you can't (normally) insert child record if its parent doesn't exist, so child table's trigger can't fire before master table's one.
SQL> create table table_a
  2    (id_a    number primary key,
  3     name    varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table table_b
  2    (id_b    number primary key,
  3     id_a    number references table_a (id_a),
  4     address varchar2(10));

Table created.

This will fail because there's no parent record:
SQL> insert into table_b (id_b, id_a, address) values (1, 100, 'Croatia');
insert into table_b (id_b, id_a, address) values (1, 100, 'Croatia')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C00157817) violated - parent key not
found
    

Let's create parent first:
SQL> insert into table_a( id_a, name) values (100, 'Little');

1 row created.

OK; child can now be inserted:
SQL> insert into table_b (id_b, id_a, address) values (1, 100, 'Croatia');

1 row created.


Another option is to use deferrable foreign key constraint which lets you insert child records although parent doesn't exist. Control is done at the moment of commit.
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> drop table table_b;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table table_b
  2    (id_b    number primary key,
  3     id_a    number references table_a (id_a) initially deferred deferrable,
  4     address varchar2(10));

Table created.

Inserting child record: now it works!
SQL> insert into table_b (id_b, id_a, address) values (1, 100, 'Croatia');

1 row created.

However, if I commit, error is being raised:
SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C00157819) violated - parent key not
found

Is anything stored? Nope:
SQL> select * from table_b;

no rows selected

OK, so let's start over: child first:
SQL> insert into table_b (id_b, id_a, address) values (1, 100, 'Croatia');

1 row created.

Parent next (I didn't commit!):
SQL> insert into table_a( id_a, name) values (100, 'Little');

1 row created.

Commit at the end:
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Tables' contents:
SQL> select * from table_a;

      ID_A NAME
---------- ----------
       100 Little

SQL> select * From table_B;

      ID_B       ID_A ADDRESS
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100 Croatia

SQL>


Therefore, do the same: use deferrable constraints and you should be OK, regardless of triggers' firing sequence.

But my doubt is for example, although the trigger is executed in the child table after the parent table, is there a chance the execution of the trigger might be slower in the parent table(lets imagine we have a complex trigger in the parent table) for whatever reason and when the trigger of the child table fires, the execution of the trigger of the parent table is not finished already and therefore we can get an error?.

Try it and then you tell me. Even if it fails, now that you know the workaround (deferrable foreign key constraint), I wouldn't worry.

First, make your entry in table A and in the trigger on insert, first insert in table C and insert in table B and update table A for fk table B and in on insert table B, insert table D and in trigger on insert table D update table C for fk;
